# Wrong usage of "versus"

Tags: grammar, word-choice

A friend of mine has written:

"*Iraq! You gave us a war! vs., we'll give you Haftsin.*"

Isn't this sentence wrong? AFAIK we can say: "Iraq, you gave us a war; but we['ll] give you Haftsin".

I have never seen vs. like that in a sentence and I feel it is incorrect, but since I am a foreigner learning English I thought it's better to ask.

---

ps. Haftsin (meaning 7 Ses) is a tradition in Iran in which we decorate somewhere (at Nowrooz, which like Christmas is the beginning of the year) using seven things which begin with Sin -which is the equivalent letter to S in Persian.

Comment: It would be fine if you were comparing two actual quotes: *Iraq! "You gave us war!" vs. "We'll give you Haftsin."*

Comment: @JasonBassford actually the purpose is to say that "Iraq, although you gave us war, we give you peace (through Haftsin)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sentence looks wrong. You can judge it for yourself - just replace *vs* with its definition to check if the resulting sentence makes sense. For example, Merriam-Webster defines *versus* as either *against*, *in contrast to* or *as the alternative of*. It's clear that none of these is appropriate in your case.

However, the sentence you proposed may be improved as well. You have two independent clauses, *Iraq, you gave us a war* and *we'll give you Haftsin*, which can be joined by either a semicolon without a conjunction

> Iraq, you gave us a war; we'll give you Haftsin.

or a comma followed by the coordinating conjunction *but*

> Iraq, you gave us a war, but we'll give you Haftsin.